# How can I create a task that will auto split a date/time stamp column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In DBeaver I am pulling date and time from a couple of different places in the database. Some of the results separate the date and time but I have one column pulling them in together. Can I create a task with instructions to automatically split the date and time stamp into 2 separate columns?

[image: triage_date_time vs arrival_date and arrival_time]

Comment: `SELECT triage_date_time::time AS triage_time, triage_date_time::date AS triage_date`

Comment: Do you want a query? A view? Virtual columns? Maybe
 you want to hard code duplicate data???

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 ways of doing this.

1. You can always generate virtual columns on selecting. Example: `select triage_date_time, triage_date_time::date as arrival_date, triage_date_time::time as arrival_time from your table;`
2. Add to your table 2 new columns. `ALTER TABLE yourtable ADD "arrival_time" time null, ADD "arrival_date" date null`. After then create a trigger before insert and update process, inside the trigger function write your updated SQL code for these fields. Example: `new.arrival_date = new.triage_date_time::date; new.arrival_time = new.triage_date_time::time`.
3. Same as the second way, but instead of the trigger you can write updated SQL codes in the DB function (function for inserting, if you have a function)  or in the back-end project code